# The items of Object mode tool bar

Tags: object-mode, tools

Why is the number of items in the toolbar in the Object Mode different? I followed a beginner tutorial of Blender, and I found that the number of toolbar of mine is 9 while the blogger's is 11, and I don't know how to get to the toolbar like his, anyone can help me with this, thanks.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please link the tutorial you're talking about?

Comment: it could be from an addon.

Comment: Yes, it's from addons which named Hardops and boxcutter